# How to simulate Caps Lock keystrokes with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I know there is an action class where this is possible, but I just understand common keys, such as: enter, backspace, and tab. For instance:

```
action.sendKeys (Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

For modifier keys---Caps Lock, Control, Option, Command---it is not very clear how to use `sendKeys`?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) a list of the keys you can send.

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply, but I can not find specific examples.
I was just learning the selenium, can you give me an example? **How simulate keystrokes Caps Lock key?** such as pressing the enter key: `action.sendKeys (Keys.ENTER). perform ();`

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://watirwebdriver.com/sending-special-keys/) might be help you out:

Based on that, you can create a function, which can simulate caps lock ON e.g.

(just a rough function)

```
def send_caps_keys(keys):
  for key in keys:
    element.send_keys [:shift, key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help get you started.
You can hack in a caps lock key into `selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py`
In the Keys class I added the following line:

```
CAPS         = '\ue21EA'
```

Then I fired up webdriver and pointed it at a [JavaScript Caps Lock detector](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/jscapslock/jscapslock.html)

I found the element and sent it the CAPS key. Then the webpage returned a caps lock warning

```
x = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
x.send_keys(Keys.Keys.CAPS)
```

If your goal is checking whether caps lock is on or off, this should help.